# Puppet Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

Tags: puppet

Hi I'm on **Kali** linux user trying to set up Puppet Clients and Servers on **DietPi** linux

```
# sudo puppet  config set server user.example.com
```

While running Puppet:

```
# puppet agent -v --test
Error: request https://user.example.com:8140//puppet-ca/v1/certificate/ca failed: Failed to open TCP connection to user.example.com:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)                                                                  
Error: Could not request certificate: Failed to open TCP connection to user.example.com:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

Comment: what is your: `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` content? Per the `puppet config` output, puppet can't read your config, or you forgot to paste it? Then, why is your agent connecting to: `https://user.example.com:8140/`. Is `user.example.com` a valid CNAME for you or you obfuscated the URL in this message for security reasons ?

Answer (score 0):

This error is because agent is unable convert user.example.com to an ipaddress, so you need to  add it to your /etc/hosts file to point out that.

And make sure that 8140 port is opened in master side as well, incase any firewall in between.